# How to catch an event every time UIWebView loads a request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm building a simple iOS app with UIWebView. Inside the Web View I'm loading a request with URL of a specific page. This page redirects me into another page and I'd like to execute a method when the redirect happens.

So basically I'm looking for a solution which would help me discover when another request is called so I can execute a method every time it happens. I couldn't find any event like this in Apple Documentation so I was thinking if you could help me with it? It should work with hyperlinks, redirects, etc.

Regards,
avi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144616/how-to-detect-redirect-in-a-uiwebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about the UIWebViewDelegate protocol.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Specifically this method will be of interest.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Comment: Thx, just found it too. I would up vote but I can't unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

does the trick, just customize the request to fill your needs.