# URL saved from UIWebview does not correspond to the True Url

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiwebview

My problem is the following. I have an application that asks the user to insert a Url on Wikipedia. For example the user inserts :

```
URLInserted = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA".
```

Inserting this URL opens the page

```
TrueURl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States"
```

that is the real URL of the Unites States page on Wikipedia. Once the page is loaded I save the current URL into a variable. When I print the string contained in the variable the URL that is printed is the `URLInserted` and NOT `TrueURL`. I would like that the URL that I save into my variable is the `TrueURL` of the United States page and not the `URLInserted` by the user.  How can I solve this issue? This is the function that I use to get the URL :

```
currentUrl = String(describing: WebView.request?.mainDocumentURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia redirects you to the page the user inserted. If you compare the two, the `path/USA` is redirected from `path/United_States`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to solve. One idea: you can look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144616/how-to-detect-redirect-in-a-uiwebview) for how to listen for redirects from the web view.